# Can $\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$ be written as $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}$ when $h=x-x_0$?

Tags: calculus, limits, tangent-line

Say that we have a function $f(x)=x$, and two distinct points $P(x_0,f(x_0))$ and $Q(x,f(x))$ on the curve $y=f(x)$; if we let Q approach P, then the slope of the secant through Q and P will approach a limit, that is the slope of the tangent line at P: $$m_{tan}= \lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0} . . . . . (1)$$
I have read that if we let $h$ denote the difference $h=x-x_0$, then the statement $x\to x_0$ is equivalent to the statement $h\to 0$, so we can rewrite $(1)$ in terms of $x_0$ and $h$ as:$$m_{tan}= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h} . . . . . (2)$$
Okay, if someone said that since $h$ denote the difference $h=x-x_0$, then the statement $h\to 0$ is equivalent to the statement $x_0\to x$, so we can rewrite $(2)$ as:$$m_{tan}=\lim_{x_0\to x}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0} . . . . . (3)$$
BUT, this is totally wrong since $(1)$ and $(3)$ are totally different limits that give slops of tangents of two different points(namely, $P$ and $Q$).

Can $(1)$ be written as $(2)$? If yes, why can't $(2)$ be written as $(3)$?

Answer (score 2):

Yes of course those are two equivalent ways to write the limits by a change of variables.

Note also that in the definition $x\to x_0$ the value $x_0$ is fixed and $x$ is approching that value at the point $P$.

Therefore, to summarize, starting from

$$\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$$

by the change of variable $x=x_0+h \iff x-x_0=h$ we have that $x\to x_0 \iff h\to 0$ and

$$\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}$$

Comment: Maybe you didn't read to the end.
Won't $h→0$ not only when $x→x_0$ but also when $x_0→x$?
If yes then $\lim_{x→x_0}\frac{f(x)−f(x_0)}{x−x_0}=\lim_{h→0}\frac{f(x_0+h)−f(x0)}{h}=\lim_{x_0→x}\frac{f(x)−f(x0)}{x−x_0}$

Comment: but the first limit here is the slope of the tangent at P, and the last is the slope at Q!

Comment: @مُحَمَّدْ Yes I've read that point and as specified in the definition we are considering $x_0$ fixed.

Comment: @مُحَمَّدْ Both are the slope of the tangent at $x=x_0$ that is at $P(x_0,f(x_0))$.

Comment: So $h\to 0$ means $x \to x_0$ but not $x_0 \to x$ because we are considering $P$ fixed?

Comment: Yes exactly, that’s the point!

Answer (score 1):

One way to see what is really going on with (1) (2) and (3) is looking at concrete examples. You let $f(x)=x$ at the beginning of your post but never use it again.

- In (1), 
  $$
  \lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0} = \lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{x-x_0}{x-x_0}=1.
  $$
- In (2), 
  $$
  \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(x_0+h)-x_0}{h}=1.
  $$

Let's consider another example: $f(x)=x^2.$

- In (1), 
  $$
  \lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0} 
  = \lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{x^2-x_0^2}{x-x_0}
  = \lim_{x\to x_0} (x+x_0)=2x_0.
  $$
- In (2), 
  $$
  \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(x_0+h)^2-x_0^2}{h}
  =\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(x_0+h+x_0)h}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}2x_0+h=2x_0.
  $$

---

> the statement $h→0$ is equivalent to the statement $x_0→x$

No! It is not that they are equivalent or not, but that "$h→0$" and "$x_0→x$" are **not** mathematical statements at all.

> Can (1) be written as (2)?

Both (1) and (2) have the same value whenever exist. Either one of them, when exists, defines the *derivative* of $f$ at $x_0$.

> If yes, why can't (2) be written as (3)?

In the case when the notation $x_0$ is some given *fixed* number, the expression
$$
\lim_{x_0\to x}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0))}{x-x_0}
$$
is meaningless. It is something like 
$$
\lim_{1\to x}\frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1},
$$
which is meaningless. If you are considering the following two *expressions*:
$$
\lim_{x\to y}\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y},\quad \lim_{y\to x}\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}
$$
they are in general two different things. Again, using the example $f(x)=x^2$, you can see that 
$$
\lim_{x\to y}\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}=2y,
$$
but 
$$
\lim_{y\to x}\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}=2x.
$$

Comment: Okay, thank you, but I still got some problems. Can't I write $(1)$ as: $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(x-h)}{h}$? If I solved this for $f(x)=x^2$, I will get $2x$, which is the value of $(3)$ for $f(x)=x^2$ assuming that $x_0$ is a variable and $x$ is a constant!

Comment: @مُحَمَّدْ I think one should stick to one set of notations to avoid all possible confusion. Mathematically, there is no difference among the expressions: $f(x), f(z), f(y), f(x_0), f(\text{whatever letter you would like to put here})$, etc. However, in a given piece of argument, once one defines/claims a set of notation, one should not change the meaning of it anymore. For instance, given that in your example, $x_0$ is a constant, one should never use the symbol $x_0$ as a "variable" anymore. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) There are many equivalent formulations of the derivative $f'(x)$: for instance $f'(x)= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$, $f'(x)=\lim_{y\to x}\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}$, $f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x-h)-f(x)}{-h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(x-h)}{h}$. Without a specific goal in mind, I don't find algebraic manipulation of theses expressions very interesting.

Comment: if I defined $x_0=c, \text{c is a constant}$, but also $x_0=h+x, \text{h and x are variables}$. Is $x_0$ a constant or a variable? That is what I did to turn $(2)$ into the limit in my comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you keep the point $p$ fixed and move the point $q$ then you find the slope at $p$

On the other hand if you keep $q$ fixed and move $p$ towards $q$ you get slope at point $q$

Usually they keep $ x_o$ fixed and let $x$ approach $ x_0$

Comment: Fine, but the book says that we can rewrite $(1)$ as $(2)$[since $x\to x_0$ is equivalent to $h\to 0$]. Hence, can we rewrite $(2)$ as $\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x_0)-f(x)}{x_0-x}$[since $h\to 0$ is equivalent to $x_0\to x$]!!? but this limit and $(1)$ are totally different limits that will give slopes of tangents at different points!

Comment: $\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x_0)-f(x)}{x_0-x}= \lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0} = f'(x_0)$ You are multiplying top and bottom by a negative one. That does not change the fraction.

Comment: Sorry. I meant to write the limit in my comment as $\lim_{x_0\to x}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$

Comment: That is $f'(x)$ which is different  from $f'(x_0)$ as you have said before.